# how to install ubuntu 10.04 on latest hp 9th Gen server with 64 GB Ram?

Tags: hardware, python, ubuntu-10.04

How to install Ubuntu 10.04 on latest HP 9th Gen. Xeon Servers with 64 GB RAM?

We are able to install Ubuntu 12.04 but below that we are not able to do?

Our software (erp) runs safe and sound only on the 10.04 with Python 2.6.5 and required packages support.

If we upgrade from Ubuntu 10.04 version we cannot run Software.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

### First - Let's take a step back...

Looking at the [Ubuntu LTS information](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS), **10.04 LTS is no longer supported by Canonical and I would not install new server workloads on it. I'd explore all other alternatives before I deployed 10.04 for anything that matters. Seriously.**

If the problem is Python 2.6. A better question is:
[How can I install Python 2.6 on Ubuntu 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125342/how-can-i-install-python-2-6-on-12-04)

Installing Python from a PPA may not be ideal, but it's a lot better than running an OS with no support or security fixes. The answer also references [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv), which may also be useful for isolating Python 2.6 and libraries in newer environments.

### Virtualize

That said, if the application absolutely cannot run on Ubuntu 12.04 or later, my advice is to virtualize your workload for now, and come up with a plan as soon as possible to get it onto a newer OS. Sometimes the real world doesn't leave us the choices we'd like. 12.04 is supported for another year or so, 14.04 for much longer (1).  Virtualizing is often a good idea anyway, although every situation is different. 95% of my workloads are virtual.

Run it under a hypervisor of your choice, like Microsoft's Hyper-V (2) or VMWare's ESX/ESXi. Then, your question is not "how do I install Ubuntu 10.04 on an HP Gen9 server", it is "how do I get my application to work on 12.04 or later ASAP".

This takes drivers/hardware support out of the equation. It also gives you more options/flexibility when upgrading if you only have one of these Gen9 servers) as VMs are both a lot easier to move around, and since you can have more than one VM on the server (much more), you can spin up and work on the replacement VM while your other VM is still running.

### Make a Plan to Move to a Newer OS ASAP

If you do install 10.04, then strongly recommend coming up with a plan to get the software (whether the vendor you got it from or if it was written in-house) onto a modern OS that is supported by a vendor and receiving bug fixes and security updates as soon as possible. **Whether 5 years or 10 years after release, when the OS is no longer supported by the vendor, it is a serious risk.**

#### Sides Notes

1. Yes, I'm aware 16.04 LTS is out. It needs a few months to stabilize, though.
2. Given 10.04's age, while should run under Hyper-V, it may not be ideal. 12.04 and later are much better. I have no experience running it under VMWare, but I suspect it works.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't install that old Ubuntu OS on modern HP hardware. Use period-correct hardware (DL-series G7) or virtualize.

Here's [HP's Ubuntu support matrix](http://h17007.www1.hpe.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/supportmatrix/ubuntu.aspx).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has a link for [Old Ubuntu Releases](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/), including [Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS (Lucid Lynx)](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/lucid/).